# Pushing a ViewController while the App is in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way i can push my viewcontroller while my app is in background state? For background activity i am using the following code in appdelegate.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by push a view controller? Push it to where? What do you want to happen? If your app is in the background then pushing view controllers is irrelevant as nothing will happen on the screen.

Comment: Actually i have a scenerio in which a timer is running and on its completion a GUI will appear with which user is suppose to interact and if he doesn't then the GUI will disappear after exact 1 min with its respective API Call.

Comment: Yes, but the GUI will not appear while the app is in the background. The best thing to do is when the app comes into the foreground to check your timer and present the correct screen based on the state of it at that point.

Comment: Not to mention that you shouldn't run a timer in the background either.

Comment: Why shouldn't i run a timer in the background?